# How make sound louder programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios

In my iphone application I am using Voice Over. Is it possible to make voice Over sound more louder programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

```
MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
musicPlayer.volume = 1;
```

You can read about MPMusicPlayerController here: [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Using this code you could make sound more louder programmatically.